# Display list with sub list and sub total in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I try to have a nive list and sublist of item to display in R (possibly collapsible) as the kind of thing we could have in a pivot table in Excel.
Is there a way to do it with the package DT for example?

The final result should look like this
[table with item and sub items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMmh6.png).

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and revise your question. Some data snippets, your expected output and what you tried so far is always useful.

Comment: Please see this related question for a more conform question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831836/using-rowsgroup-in-shiny-dt Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using rpivoTable functionalities.

```
rpivotTable(data, rows = NULL, cols = NULL, aggregatorName = NULL,
  vals = NULL, rendererName = NULL, sorter = NULL, exclusions = NULL,
  inclusions = NULL, ..., width = NULL, height = NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Nevertheless, I know rpivoTable and it is lacking some of the DT nice feature such as: ordering, copy/past button, conditional formatting, columns formatting etc...

This is not what I am looking for here.

Comment: No unfortunately not. I am currently working on this possible solution but I didn't manage to make it work for the moment. Any suggestion are welcome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831836/using-rowsgroup-in-shiny-dt

Comment: Take a look at my post, I am very close, only have a strange issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933859/how-to-add-totals-to-a-dtdatatable

Comment: Version 0.2.0 of `rpivotTable` now on Cran has ability to order rows and columns.